# How to get Text-property from an argument with Object-type in C#?

Tags: c#

I have such button click handler:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(sender.Text);
}
```

I want know the Text-value from the sender object. How to do it if sender has object-type, which can't include Text-property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it:

```
var control = sender as Control;
if(control != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(control.Text);
}
```

Comment: `var control = sender as Control;
if(control != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(control.Text);
}`

control in the Show, not sender.